# Storing raster data with Java into Oracle Spatial

Tags: raster, java, software-recommendations, oracle-spatial

I have a Java application that processes raster data.
At the end of the process I plan to store the raster in oracle spatial.

What is the best way to do this?

I had a look at geotools but I did not find a solution there.

Is 'wrapping GDAL' the best way and, if so, then how?

Or is there a workaround or a strategy available?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps look at all the APIs that come with Oracle Spatial Georaster.

One of them is a Java  API that lets you manipulate rasters. See the **oracle.spatial.georaster** package in http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPAJV/toc.htm

To download the Java API see http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/GEORS/geor_intro.htm#GEORS1179. The API proper comes with your database installation in $ORACLE_HOME/md/jlib/georasterapi.jar